# Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2 org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to move my project to `Spring Boot 2.0.0.M2`.

Right now I faced a following issue:

```
The import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank cannot be resolved
```

In the Maven classpath I have:

```
Hibernate Validator 5.4.1.Final
```

[image]

Where `@NotBlank` annotation is now located ?

Comment: what is your pom look like?

Comment: My pom is a quite big so I have update my question with a Dependency Hierarchy view

Comment: I'd guess that Maven corrupted the jar when it downloaded the dependency. Try purging Maven's cache to force it to download it again

Comment: It did the trick ! Thanks !